# How do peak/off peak times work on the TfL network with the Oyster card?

Tags: public-transport, london, fares, tfl, oyster-card

The [section](https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/ticket-types/on-oyster#on-this-page-3) on TfL's website dealing with peak and off-peak times specifies the times but it doesn't specify if those are considered when card holders touch in or when they touch out.

Say, I board a train at 18:45 from Euston and arrive at Watford Junction at 19:07. The journey started during the peak time but ended during the off-peak time. What fare will I be charged - the peak or the off-peak?

Comment: I believe that it is when you touch in, but I am not completely certain.

Comment: Probably, as it otherwise might be an incentive for people to travel extra long times just so they can touch in at a peak time and touch out at an off-peak time. But I couldn't find this explicitly clarified on TfL's website.

Comment: @Nobilis: That's probably not a relevant consideration. The ticketing system assumes that _most_ people are just interested in getting from point A to point B and have no particular wish to ride around in peak-hour trains just for the fun of it. Someone who is okay with arriving at point B late would have more of an incentive to do something interesting at point A instead and then take a later train, than to take an earlier, fuller, train from A and then hang around waiting on the platform at B, even if both options would cost him the same.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I phoned TfL to find the answer to this. It's simple and straightforward:

#### The rate depends on when you touch in.

Peak fares apply from 06:30 to 09:29 and from 16:00 to 18:59 Monday to Friday (excluding public holidays). Off-peak fares apply at all other times. That is, if you touch in during those two three-hour periods, you will be charged the peak fare.

If your journey starts in off-peak time but strays into the peak period, it's still an off-peak fare.

Comment: Right, I guess that's as good as it gets, it would be nice if they were to put it up on their website.

Comment: So it is the same as trains with reductions on the OV-chipcard in the Netherlands, but NS puts it loud and clear on the website. Check in after 8:55 and your journey is classed as after 9:00AM and goes as reduction, (so off peak.)

Comment: Note that the specific journey mentioned, Euston to Watford Junction, benefits from contraflow off peak pricing. [As shown in the Single Fare Finder](https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/fares/single-fare-finder?From=London+Euston+Rail+Station&FromId=910GEUSTON&To=Watford+Junction+Rail+Station&ToId=910GWATFDJ&PassengerType=Adult), making this journey (in this direction) in the morning counts as *off* peak (because you are going against the flow)

Answer (score 4):

There is a 5 min grace period So Peak is from 635 to 927 And from 1605 to 1857

https://tfl.gov.uk/corporate/transparency/freedom-of-information/foi-request-detail?referenceId=FOI-1798-1718